# Include Abstract & References page in ToC using tocbibind

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, abstract, tocbibind

The code below will print a table of contents that lists the Contents page, section and subsection. The contents page itself is on page ii, and the abstract should come before it, but it doesn't appear on the ToC. Also, how would I get the bibliography on my ToC as well? Given that I don't use a dedicated  `\section{Bibliography}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\section*{Abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subection of Section 1}

\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using a `KOMA-Script` class, simply replace `\section*{Abstract}` with `\addsec{Abstract}` (`\addsec` produces an unnumbered section that is added to the ToC and correctly changes headers).

To include the bibliography (which presumably is produced with `biblatex`) in the ToC, use `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`.